# How to align images side by side using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to place three images on my page with text description underneath and three more images underneath those with text description underneath those images.

I need to create this using only HTML and CSS but not using Flex.

I've managed to get all 6 images going down the left of my page but no matter what I try - float, display, grid etc, I can not get a simple result.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please add your code including what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `grid` like you mentioned. you would used the `grid-template-column` property to define how you want your columns to be look.

Here I used 3 columns (`1fr` per column) to show an image and some text under it.

There are other ways to do this but `grid` is great for this kind of thing. You can then use a media query on `.grid` to `display: block` for mobile if you wanted them to stack

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=640:*" alt="a dog" />
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=640:*" alt="a dog" />
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=640:*" alt="a dog" />
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setting the page up in a 'row' :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<style>
   .column {
     float: left;
     width: 33.33%;
     padding: 5px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: You may have problems with this as the padding ( x 2) added to 33.33% (all x 3) could come to more than 100% - did you try it? box-sizing plus removing browser default margin/padding could help though.